# How to change group check box state with external button check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this snippet. How can I change check second checkbox on `.change` click?

```js
$(".change").on("click", function(){
   
});
```

```css
body{
padding:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> item 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> item 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> item 3
  </label>
</div>
<br />
<br />

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default change">Item 2</button>
```

Comment: Change how?  Just toggle it? Or always select it?  Also you have the majority of the logic, really.  What difficulty are you having doing this yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I will correctly understand your question.

```js
$( '.change' ).on( 'click' , function(){
  /* $( 'label' ).removeClass( 'active' ); */
  $( 'label:nth-child(2)' ).addClass( 'active' );
  /* $( 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked' ).prop( 'checked', false ); */
  $( 'input[type="checkbox"]' )[ 1 ].checked = true;

  console.log( 'Second item is checked: ' + $( 'input[type="checkbox"]' )[ 1 ].checked )
} );
```

```css
body{
  padding: 30px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> item 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> item 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> item 3
  </label>
</div>
<br />
<br />

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default change">Button</button>
```